# In RSpec, how can one pass an instance variable to an example block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I am using some spec_helper.rb methods to generate RSpec examples and one of them is dependent on data from another one.

Example `spec_helper.rb`:

```
def it_should_be_big(objects)
  @tested_objects ||= []

  objects.each do |obj|
    it "should be big (#{obj.name})" do
      obj.should be_big
    end
  end

  @tested_objects += objects
end

def it_should_be_small(objects)
  @tested_objects ||= []

  objects.each do |obj|
    it "should be small (#{obj.name})" do
      obj.should be_small
    end
  end

  @tested_objects += objects
end

def it_should_have_tested_for_all_objects
  it "should test for all objects" do
    @tested_objects ||= []

    (all_objects - @tested_objects).should == []

    @tested_objects = []
  end
end
```

Example `something_spec.rb`:

```
describe "something" do
  it_should_be_big(some_objects)
  it_should_be_small(some_other_objects)

  it_should_have_tested_for_all_objects
end
```

I know the code does not make much sense but it follows the actual code where it matters (the `@tested_objects` variable).

When I run the specs, it can't find the @tested_objects variable (I guess it uses another variable space for inside the example blocks). **Is there a way to pass the variable to inside the example block of the final helper method?**

RSpec 2.5, Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation you may want `before` or [`share_examples_for`](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Example/ExampleGroupMethods/it_should_behave_like#618-Reusing-shared-examples).

---

workaround: it seems that only local variables are seen by the `it`. Then you can try this:

```
def it_should_have_tested_for_all_objects
  @tested_objects ||= []

  tested_objects = @tested_objects
  it "should test for all objects" do
    (all_objects - tested_objects).should == []
  end

  @tested_objects = []
end
```

Comment: This is not plausible in my situation. I need to either share a variable between multiple examples (not good) or set it up outside the examples but access it from inside the examples.

Comment: @vrinek: See my edit for a possible solution. However, in my humble opinion, you shouldn't use helpers like that :)